# Best way for an American to meet people in France to travel with

Tags: europe, france, us-citizens

Looking for the best sites or information on meeting people or a group to travel Europe with. I am new to Europe from America and by myself and want to travel to see the cool places in Europe.

Looking for information on where to meet like-minded people to plan trips with.

Comment: Can you help us out by being more specific about what 'like-minded' means to you? Church groups? The Gym?  Bird watching? History buffs?  You can help give insight by explaining how you meet like-minded people in America, it's probably going to be the same, or much the same.  Hanging out in a youth hostile will expose you to travellers, but not necessarily like-minded travellers.  Close voting as 'unclear'

Comment: Tripr is a new app I've been using lately. Not tried it in France but it seems enormously popular in São Paulo for some reason.

Comment: Indeed, what do you want to do? Maybe museums bore you and you want to go to [Hellfest](http://www.hellfest.fr/en/)? You should be specific as to the sorts of things you are interested in. Then you will find the right people!

Answer (score 1):

(disclaimer, I've just heard about them recently, and never used them as I prefer discover by myself)

I would look at "greeters" : http://www.globalgreeternetwork.info/

Here is the France greeters' map: http://www.greeters.fr/?page_id=878&lang=en

Max.

Comment: The 'greeters' appear to be local volunteers.  Are they the sort to pick up and go to the cool places in Europe?  Wouldn't that interfere with their volunteering commitment?

Comment: In my mind, one must do at least a little bit of research before traveling; decide where you want to go; if wanting to see Paris, then look for greeters in Paris, if wanting to go to Berlin, look for greeters there. If OP just want to "follow" then an organized travel group might be better.